# How to encode (serialize) and decode (deserialize) AMF packets?

Tags: php, flash, serialization, remoting, amf

At the moment it seems I've tried every trick in the book trying to get this to work. I need some way of encoding AMF requests and then decoding the responses. At this point I don't care what language it's in, as long as it's doable and free (as in to me), however I would prefer PHP.

I don't know what other information is needed, but I'm happy to supply more info - just comment this!

Thanks.

EDIT:
It seems the version of AMFPHP I was using was broken. Using a different version that I extracted from somewhere worked.

Comment: it would be great if you could post how you did it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [amfphp](http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/) for PHP side or from the [zend framework](http://framework.zend.com/download/amf) or [weborb for PHP](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-php/overview.html) who is also free

Comment: how exactly? Every time i've tried to serialize my $amf object, with $serializer = new AMFSerializer();
 $result = $serializer->serialize($amf); 
it doesn't come back with the correct response.

Comment: I dont know too less information. What are you serializing, what are you expecting ?

Comment: trying to serialize something so the end result is like: http://adammw.homeip.net:8888/amf/fvill.dat

for example, if you  $amf = new AMFObject(file_get_contents('http://adammw.homeip.net:8888/amf/fvill.dat'));
 $deserializer = new AMFDeserializer($amf->rawData);
 $deserializer->deserialize($amf); then try and serialize it again with $serializer = new AMFSerializer();
 $result = $serializer->serialize($amf); the $result is different from the input, and not just different, but plain wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is very old, but still if someone is searching like me.
Checkout the answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12511536/1124037)

Answer (score 0):

SabreAMF has a decoder. Check http://code.google.com/p/sabreamf/