# How to decode AS3 object encoded in AMF3 in PHP

Tags: php, actionscript-3, apache-flex, amf, amfphp

I am trying to decode an object sent through sockets from Flash in PHP.
I tried using AMFPHP and ZEND_AMF but neither did worked.

Can someone point me to the way of decoding the AMF3 encoded objects in php without using remote functionality of the AMFPHP? 
Data is send thorough sockets, so I cannot use the remote objects as usually amfphp works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ivan Dyachenko Thanks for pointing towards SabreAMF
Below is the way I successfully decoded and mapped the AMF3 encoded object received from Flex/Flash on sockets

```
include_once 'SabreAMF/AMF3/Serializer.php';
include_once 'SabreAMF/AMF3/Deserializer.php';
include_once 'SabreAMF/OutputStream.php';
include_once 'SabreAMF/InputStream.php';
include_once 'SabreAMF/TypedObject.php';
include_once 'SabreAMF/ClassMapper.php';

/************DECODER*****************/
SabreAMF_ClassMapper::registerClass('FLASH_CLASS_NAME','PHP_CLASS_NAME'); //CLASSES SHOULD BE SAME
$inputStream = new SabreAMF_InputStream($buffer);
$des = new SabreAMF_AMF3_Deserializer($inputStream);
$obj = $des->readAMFData();
//$obj will contain the instance of PHP_CLASS_NAME with the properties set as the values sent by Flex/Flash
/************END DECODER*****************/

/**************ENCODER******************/
$classObj = new PHP_CLASS(); //PHP_CLASS is your class
$object = new SabreAMF_TypedObject('FLASH_CLASS_NAME',$classObj); //FLASH_CLASS_NAME IS NAME OF CLASS AVAILABLE TO FLASH FOR MAPPING
$outputStream = new SabreAMF_OutputStream();
$serializer = new SabreAMF_AMF3_Serializer($outputStream);
$serializer->writeAMFData($object);
$output = $outputStream->getRawData();

//$output is AMF Encoded string to be sent to FLEX/FLASH. 
/***********END ENCODER***************/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SabreAMF](https://github.com/evert/SabreAMF) to encode/decode AMF data on PHP.

Comment: I am trying to use SabreAMF, below is the code 
`
$data = $_POST['data']; 
include 'SabreAMF/Server.php';
$server = new SabreAMF_Server($data);
foreach($server->getRequests() as $request) {  
$server->setResponse($request['response'],SabreAMF_Const::R_RESULT,    $request['data']  // Any data structure, in this case we are echoing back the original data
 );

}

echo $server->sendResponse();
`
I am getting this error : Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Buffer underrun at position: 6. Trying to fetch 15653 bytes' in /var/www/html/sockets/SabreAMF/InputStream.php:56

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this - https://github.com/neoxic/php-amf3 - this is a very reliable PHP extension for encoding/decoding AMF3 streams.